# How can I center the column headers in longtabu with the right aligned columns?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, longtabu

Tried centering but that did not work:

```
\begin{longtabu}{|r|r|} %\textwidth
\hline
\centering \boldmath  $X$ & \centering \boldmath $Y$ \tabularnewline
\hline 
$-9.644$ &  $93.000$   \\
\hline
$1.997$ &  $3.988$   \\
\hline
\end{longtabu}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without of help of any packages:

```
\begin{longtabu}{|r|r|} %\textwidth
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{$\bm{X}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\bm{Y}$} \tabularnewline
\hline 
$-9.644$ &  $93.000$   \\
\hline
$1.997$ &  $3.988$   \\
\hline
\end{longtabu}
```

for `\bm` is needed package `bm`

[image]

Comment: Added the pipes around `c` as in `|c|` and it worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

The usual `\multicolumn{1}{<alignment>}{<content>}` can help. Also, use `\mathbf{X}` to get **`X`** bold in mathmode instead of `\boldmath X`. Furthermore, instead of manually switching to mathmode in each cell, the `>{$} r <{$}` specification in the header will suffice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,tabu}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu}{| >{$}r<{$} | >{$}r<{$} |} %\textwidth
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{$\mathbf{X}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\mathbf{Y}$} \\
\hline 
-9.644 & 93.000  \\
\hline
1.997  & 3.988   \\
\hline
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `tabu`'s `\rowfont [alignment]{font spec}` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabu} to 15em {| X[r] | X[r] |} \hline
\everyrow{\hline}
\rowfont[c]{\bfseries}
X & Y \\
-9.644 & 93.000 \\
1.997 & 3.988 \\
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of the above code]

(If you don't want the first line bold, you could just use `\rowfont[c]{}`, of course.)

Unfortunately the `\rowfont[c]` seems ignored when in math mode, I don't get why. But if you don't need math mode it's the simplest and prettiest solution imho.